# Is there a mapping in the standard library between Swift's String.Encoding and the IANA character set names?

Tags: swift, character-encoding

Does a mapping exist in the standard library between the `String.Encoding` enumeration and the standard IANA character set names, e.g., "UTF-8" for `String.Encoding.utf8`? I was not able to find one.

I'm aware that Foundation's `CFStringEncoding` can be mapped to IANA character set names, but I could not find a way to go from `String.Encoding` to `CFStringEncoding`. `CFStringEncoding` is just a type alias for `UInt32`, and the `String.Encoding` enumeration is backed by a `UInt`, but unless I've made some simple error, they do not seem to correspond.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The raw value of a `String.Encoding` is an `NSStringEncoding` and that can be converted to a `CFStringEncoding` with [`CFStringConvertNSStringEncodingToEncoding`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corefoundation/1542787-cfstringconvertnsstringencodingt). The IANA charset name is then determined with [`CFStringConvertEncodingToIANACharSetName`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corefoundation/1542710-cfstringconvertencodingtoianacha). This function returns an optional `CFString` which can be toll-free bridged to an optional Swift `String`.

Example:

```
let enc = String.Encoding.isoLatin2
let cfEnc = CFStringConvertNSStringEncodingToEncoding(enc.rawValue)
if let ianaName = CFStringConvertEncodingToIANACharSetName(cfEnc) as String? {
    print(ianaName) // iso-8859-2
}
```

Comment: Ah, `NSStringEncoding`! That was the missing link.