# How do I deal with the String.Encoding initializer never failing?

Tags: swift

```swift
if let encoding = String.Encoding(rawValue: 999) {
  // ...
}
```

Produces a compiler error saying "Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'String.Encoding'" because despite the [docs saying the String.Encoding initializer is failable](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/encoding/init(rawvalue:)), it is not and will happily create non-existent encodings.

How do I check if the encoding returned by initializer is an actual encoding?

The two ideas I have are

1. Check the String.Encoding description is not empty. This assumes that supported encodings must have a description
2. Encode something - e.g. `"abc".data(using: encoding) == nil` - which assumes that the string "abc" can be encoded by all supported encodings

Comment: I am just curious: Why do you need to create a string encoding from an arbitrary integer? If you provide more context then we might be able to suggest an better alternative.

Comment: I'm migrating an encoding preference saved in UserDefaults and I didn't want to migrate the value if it's not a valid encoding. Your Strings.availableStringEncodings looks like it's exactly what I need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation is misleading, `String.Encoding` has a non-failable

```
 public init(rawValue: UInt)
```

initializer. A list of all valid string encodings is [`String.availableStringEncodings`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/availablestringencodings), so you can use that to check the validity:

```
let encoding = String.Encoding(rawValue: 999)
print(String.availableStringEncodings.contains(encoding)) // false
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use CoreFoundation's [CFStringIsEncodingAvailable()](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corefoundation/1542860-cfstringisencodingavailable) function to check if the encoding is valid, and also if it can be used on that particular device.

However, as MartiR pointed out, `CFStringIsEncodingAvailable` needs a `CFStringEncoding` to work with, so the `String.Encoding` needs to be converted first to a CF one.

```swift
let encoding = String.Encoding(rawValue: 999)
let cfEncoding = CFStringConvertNSStringEncodingToEncoding(encoding.rawValue)

if CFStringIsEncodingAvailable(cfEncoding) {
  // ...
}
```

, or, as MartinR nicely suggested, the result of `CFStringConvertNSStringEncodingToEncoding` can also be used:

```swift
if CFStringConvertNSStringEncodingToEncoding(encoding.rawValue) != kCFStringEncodingInvalidId {
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Your method gives a false negative for `String.Encoding.shiftJIS`, `String.Encoding.windowsCP1252`, and some more.

Comment: @MartinR it's not my method, it's Apple's method :) Function docs say that it returns true for encodings available on the current system, so it might be that for some encodings, even if valid, return false.

Comment: No, the reason is that the raw value of a String.Encoding is an NSStringEncoding, and that is different from a CFStringEncoding, which is what the CFStringIsEncodingAvailable() function expects. You can convert between those representations with CFStringConvertNSStringEncodingToEncoding(), see https://stackoverflow.com/a/61177810/1187415 for an example.

Comment: `let valid = CFStringConvertNSStringEncodingToEncoding(encoding.rawValue) != kCFStringEncodingInvalidId`  would work as well.

Comment: "Function docs say that it returns true for encodings available on the current system" @Cristik, if the function docs were correct I wouldn't have this problem to begin with 